# Windows 7 Pro multi-monitor Remote Desktop software

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Since I only have Windows 7 Pro at home and at work, is there any other alternatives for multi-monitor support in a remote desktop connection?

I only found Splitview as of yet but I would like to know if there are any others.

Edit: For Remote Desktop.

Comment: Related: [Windows 7 Remote Desktop Multi Monitor Support](http://superuser.com/questions/102261/windows-7-remote-desktop-multi-monitor-support)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection can do this if you have multiple monitors:
[image: Multiple Monitors]

But I've run into issues with this before where even if you check the "Use all my monitors for the remote session" is not checked that it doesn't do it.

To fix that I've gone and edited the .rdp file and added the two following lines:

```
use multimon:i:1
span monitors:i:1
```

Once I've added that the RDP will span both monitors.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This only works if the target PC is running Windows 7 Ultimate or Windows 7 Enterprise.  (One of the few legitimate reasons to upgrade to Ultimate!)  EDIT: I would add that it's much cleaner than the old XP-compatible spanning mode - it will actually use all your monitors natively, in their correct order and resolutions, just like they were attached to the remote machine.  They even show up in Display Properties!

Comment: Shinrai, not true. I was able to make it work with Windows 7 Professional

Comment: Shinrai is correct. The remote machine must be 7 Ultimate or 7 Enterprise. See the MS frequently asked questions. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/remote-desktop-connection-faq#1TC=windows-7

Comment: The connecting client only needs Ultimate or Enterprise. I am currently testing various configurations and the remote host only needs Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: If you have win 7 pro on host, you can use RDPWrap - it seems to enable support for as well - https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to pay the 30 dollars then [Display Fusion Pro](http://www.displayfusion.com/) is the way to go!  They also offer a free version, and a 30 free trial of the Pro.  It's very easy to use, and a makes the Windows 7 mulit-monitor setup a breeze.

Comment: Does Display Fusion Pro have RDP integration via remote client?  That's very interesting, I didn't realize it was quite that sophisticated (I thought it was largely the same as UltraMon.)  I'll have to have a look.

Comment: To be honest I just got the software and haven't tried it on RDP.  I didn't realize that was what you were looking for in the question.  I'll try it out, and post back when i can.

Comment: The OP worded the question somewhat ambiguously, yes. :/